# How to call the number in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

here is my matrix setup:

```
for a in b:
    size_x = len(a) + 1
    size_y = len(b) + 1
    matrix = np.zeros ((size_x, size_y))
    for x in range(size_x):
        matrix [x, 0] = x
    for y in range(size_y):
        matrix [0, y] = y

    for x in range(1, size_x):
        for y in range(1, size_y):
            if a[x-1] == b[y-1]:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                                matrix[x-1, y] + 1,
                                matrix[x-1, y-1],
                                matrix[x, y-1] + 1
                                )
            else:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                                matrix[x-1,y] + 1,
                                matrix[x-1,y-1] + 1,
                                matrix[x,y-1] + 1
                                )
    print(matrix)
```

This would give outputs such as

```
         t   e   s   t
  [[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
 t [ 1.  0.  1.  2.  3.]
 e [ 2.  1.  0.  1.  2.]
 x [ 3.  2.  1.  1.  2.]
 t [ 4.  3.  2.  1.  1.]]
```

In which the bottom right-hand corner is the final value. How do I take this out and add it to a list?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the *i*th index of an array *arr* by using this expression: *arr[i]* .
In order to answer your question -> accessing the *bottom-right* value of a 2d matrix simply use,

```
matrix[matrix.length-1][matrix[matrix.length-1].length-1]
```

or better

```
lastRowIndex = matrix.length-1;
lastColIndex = matrix[lastRowIndex].length-1;
bottomRightValue = matrix[lastRowIndex][lastColIndex]
```